# Jquery validation of fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate the form using jquery but it's not working.
I am trying to show a red line on-field if it's empty on button click.
Below is the HTML code.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
       <div class="modal-content">
<div id="custom-form">
<div class="col-md-8">
        <form name="addData" method="post" id="addData" class="form"
              action="#"
              data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
              data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
            <fieldset class="fieldset">
                <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Fill in the fields to place your order.')) ?></span></legend>
                <fieldset class="fieldset row">
                    <div class="fields col-md-6">
                        <div class="field name required">
                            <label class="label" for="title"><span><?= $block->
                                escapeHtmlAttr(__('Full Name')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input id="bnname" title="Name" value="" class="input-text" type="text" required="true" minlength="15">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field address required">
                            <label class="label" for="title"><span><?= $block->
                                escapeHtmlAttr(__('Address')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input id="bnaddress" title="Address" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{'validate-street':true}"
                                       >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field city required">
                            <label class="label" for="title"><span><?= $block->
                                escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input id="bntext" title="City" value="" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{'validate-street':true}"
                                       >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field telephone required">
                            <label class="label" for="title"><span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Telephone')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input id="bntelephone" title="Telephone" value="" class="input-text" data-validate="{'required-number':true}"
                                       type="text" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field postalcode required">
                            <label class="label" for="title"><span><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Postal code')) ?></span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input id="bnpostalcode" title="Postal code" value="" class="input-text" data-validate="{'required-number':true}"
                                       type="text" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <div class="action submit primary buy" title="Order Now"><span><?= $block->
                        escapeHtmlAttr(__('Order Now')) ?></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
 
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure how to simply validate these fields using jquery.
Here is the jquery code

```
var isValid;
$("input").each(function() {
   var element = $(this);
   if (element.val() == "") {
       isValid = false;
   }
});
```

is there any way we can add validation to it ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?